# Google apps script - выбрать несколько Checkbox и записать наименование в ячейку

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Все привет!
Нужно сделать функцию, которая будет анализировать столбец B на значение "True" и записывать значение в ячейку С1

| A1: Название товара | B: Выбор товара |
| --- | --- |
| A2: Товар1 | True |
| A3: Товар2 | False |
| A4: Товар3 | True |

Ответ:
C1 = Товар1, Товар3

Кто-то может помочь? :)

Comment: Тут все по-другому работает. Покажите, что Вы сделали и что у Вас не получилось. Какой код написали, какую логику применили и пр пр

Comment: В профиле есть контакт - пишите.

Answer (score 0):

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;FILTER(A2:A;B2:B=TRUE))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]